# Ansible group_vars variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

A best practice approach for this is to start with a group_vars/ subdirectory named after the group. Inside of this subdirectory, create two files named vars and vault. Inside of the vars file, define all of the variables needed, including any sensitive ones. Next, copy all of the sensitive variables over to the vault file and prefix these variables with vault_. You should adjust the variables in the vars file to point to the matching vault_ variables using jinja2 syntax, and ensure that the vault file is vault encrypted. - Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html

I am using dynamic inventory and could not understand these best practices 100%.

```
group_vars/all/vars
group_vars/all/vault
```

content of vars:

```
db_username: ""
db_password: ""
```

content of vault:

```
vault_db_username: admin
vault_db_password: ****
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Fix the content of *vars*

```yaml
db_username: "{{ vault_db_username }}"
db_password: "{{ vault_db_password }}"
```

---

Details

If you want to: *`"start with a group_vars/subdirectory named after the group"`* create the inventory. For example, create the group *test*

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
hostA
hostB
```

Then create the files in *group_vars/test*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/test/vars.yml 
db_username: "{{ vault_db_username }}"
db_password: "{{ vault_db_password }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/test/vault 
vault_db_username: admin
vault_db_password: my_secret_passwd
```

Encrypt *vault*

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/test/vault
Encryption successful
shell> cat group_vars/test/vault
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
31663937333239363939313935653433663863396636376232613436306138663965633732643765
3961343439616531373830383565373838646630333533370a633362626665646465373738373466
61373961623236383933373531306562663936633433653966623366363132646165643530336264
3861383739316161340a353764376530393339666365356365356664633234393261636538666338
31626634653830656162363232653032316165326433633038653632316462636134646539636561
33303962353965393038353734356134653339383162323338633934346363393438613532333165
316363626437623366613035313036323638
```

Then the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: db_username
    - debug:
        var: db_password
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [hostA] => 
  db_username: admin
ok: [hostB] => 
  db_username: admin

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [hostA] => 
  db_password: my_secret_passwd
ok: [hostB] => 
  db_password: my_secret_passwd

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
hostA: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostB: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```